# How to fix 'A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed...' when working with dependency injection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

when reading data from the database I get this error:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous operation
>   completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

I have the following ApplicationContext.cs:

```
public class ApplicationContext : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<MyClass> MyClasses{ get; set; }
}
```

The following ApplicationContextFactory.cs

```
public class ApplicationContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationContext>
{
    public ApplicationContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationContext>();
        var connection = "myConnectionString";

        builder.UseSqlServer(connection);

        return new ApplicationContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

The following ServiceLoader.cs (where I declare the DI):

```
public static class ServiceLoader
{
    public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IRepository, Repository>();

        var connection = "myConnectionString";
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    }
}
```

and finally, the following Repository, where the exception is thrown:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private ApplicationContext _db;

    public Repository (ApplicationContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public List<MyClass> Get()
    {
        _db.MyClasses.ToList();
    }
}
```

I have also tried to declare the Repository as Transient instead of Singleton, but a similar error is thrown

> 'An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnConfiguring since it is still being configured at this point. This can happen if a second operation is started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.'

Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You should declare the context before the `Repository` singleton. Also notice that most repository implementations the hide Entity Framework are a waste of development time and give 0 value. You should have a really good explanation for hiding a Repository inside a Repository

Comment: Also notice that this model is very weird: `Repository` (a singleton) depends on a transient service (the `DbContext`)

Comment: Also, `Repository` is using `Entity Framework Core` which allows full `async` methods in a `sync` way, blocking the thread unnecessarily.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. But which approach would you suggest? The exception is thrown when I make two consecutive calls to the API that uses this repository

Comment: @joacoleza I'd suggest you to use straight EF Core with Linq and a DataAccess class that receives and returns `IQueryable<T>` for complex/re-usable queries.

Comment: Camilo, do you have any link where I can dig into this approach?

Comment: `AddDbContext` adds the `DbContext` instance as a scoped service (and not as transient @CamiloTerevinto). You should really register any service dependant on the `DbContext` as scoped or transient (never as singleton).

Comment: @FedericoDipuma That's what I meant, wasn't really sure if transient or scoped. To the OP, not really, sorry. That was the model we ended up doing in a team after digging a lot

Comment: Changing the declaration of the Repository from Singleton to Scoped fixed it. I know is not the correct way of doing so, but for now it will work. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: You should post an answer if the problem was solved

Comment: But as all you mentioned, is not a very good solution. Should I post it anyway?

Comment: Transient, Singleton cannot be Scoped! What?! I hate this _ but thanks to comments solved my problem.. my Factory was Singleton with Transient Repository.. I just made it Transient.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto , I have to disagree on your opinion that `Repository` is waste of time. It is still the way how you can build three layer architecture and separate Data Access Layer into separate project. Also it is a possibility to reuse the same code in multiple places. I often see that LINQ queries became more and more complex and instead of duplicating them you make additional layer of abstraction between your application and Database, you could use Repository or Query pattern.

Comment: @Maris It is a waste of time when it is incorrectly implemented (as most often seen in Stack Overflow questions *and* answers, and blog posts around the web). It is most often not needed either, as most projects won't actually spend the time/budget to replace something like Entity Framework

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto as I said it also a way how to complement DRY principle for big queries. And actually I had a lot of cases when I had to replace implementation of one method of repository that was widely used in system to use StoredProcedure instead of EF query(for instance). What would happen if those queries would have been scattered all across the system? :)

Answer (score 8):

In my case I found the following information helpful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

And changed the lifetime scope of my Db Context to transient using the overloaded AddDbContext method in startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyAppDbContext>(options => {
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        }, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap an async Task around your Get() function and await your results:

```
public async Task<List<MyClass>> Get()
{
   return await _db.MyClasses.ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a solution, which uses a queue. It is still single threaded, but you can call it from different threads.

```
public class ThreadSafeDataContext
    {
        private Thread databaseThread;
        private Queue<PendingQuery> pendingQueries = new Queue<PendingQuery>();
        private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();
        private bool running = true;
        public ThreadSafeDataContext()
        {
            databaseThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
            databaseThread.Start();
        }
        public void StopService()
        {
            running = false;
        }
        private void DoWork()
        {
            while(running)
            {
                if (pendingQueries.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Get and run query
                    PendingQuery query = pendingQueries.Dequeue();
                    query.result = query.action(db);
                    query.isFinished = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1); // Waiting for queries
                }
            }
        }

        public T1 Query<T1>(Func<DatabaseContext, T1> action)
        {
            Func<DatabaseContext, object> a = (DatabaseContext db) => action(db);
            PendingQuery query = new PendingQuery(a);
            pendingQueries.Enqueue(query);

            while (!query.isFinished) {
                Thread.Sleep(1); // Wait until query is finished
            }

            return (T1)query.result;
        }
    }
    class PendingQuery
    {
        public Func<DatabaseContext, object> action;
        public bool isFinished;
        public object result;

        public PendingQuery(Func<DatabaseContext, object> action)
        {
            this.action = action;
        }
    }
```

Then you can just run a query from different threads by using:

```
TeamMembers teamMembers = threadSafeDb.Query((DatabaseContext c) => c.team.ToArray())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
By Default when you inject DbContext services is Scoped. In case of Async you may getting above exception from EntityFrameworkCore.

Update Db context service from. 
  
 services.AddDbContext<DbContextClass>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });

To

 services.AddDbContext<DbContextClass>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        },ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```